# Excel Keep Sorting Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to keep a sorting range after the macro finishes running. I have data in A1:P250 and there are headers in the first row. Depending on the report, there may be additional information in rows 2 & 3. We initially added a row in between 1 & 2, then hid it and froze the top row. This works decent, but we are trying to get the sort to just work on the data we set in the macro. So if once we format it the way we want, the user can sort any column and only sort the information that should be sorted.

See [Formatted report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZB3x.png) for an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Users will sort several columns to check information, but the rows 2 & 3 in this example should stay.

Is there a way to format the report and add a sort range or something at the end before giving control back to the user so that it will sort a predetermined area?

Comment: If you are looking to leave the end user with an AutoFilter then you would have to use as headers the Cells in Row 3. You can't set AutoFilter or Sort for that matter with disjointed areas. You can just sort through macro to `A3:P250` without headers and then exit the function. I would rather suggest you place the additional information above the header row rather than below. It's never a good idea to break the logical structure of a table. Regards.

Comment: You could do a sort for ranges before and after the rows you don't want changed.

Comment: You can apply filters in your macro with something along the lines of `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="something"`. What does your vba code look like at the moment?

Comment: The autofilter could work, but I think @nbayly had the best suggestion to move those rows above the headers.